# Java Class that implements Runnable without thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have mode a class that implements the `Runnable` interface.

Now I want to start that class either multi-threaded, or non-multi-thraded (sequential) in my program according to a boolean.

How would I go about doing that? This is my current code:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = processorClass.getConstructor(constructorParameterTypes);
Processor<T> process = (Processor<T>)constructor.newInstance(constructorParameters);
RunnableProcessor<T> runnableProcessor = new RunnableProcessor<>(process, object);
if (multiThreaded) {
    new Thread(runnableProcessor).start();
}
else {
    //what to do here?
}
```

So to clarify: I want to call the `run()` method from `runnableProcessor`, without creating a thread. However I think that calling `run()` directly is deprecated, so looking for better solutions there.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by multithreded ? You col start new thread but in first option as async in sencond as synchronized.

Comment: I suggest against using raw threads for new projects. I suggest using the ExecutorService API instead. It will take care of managing the life cycle of the threads for you + it has many implementations which can provide cached, and pooled threads for you. In your code, you will use something like `executor.execute(someRunnable);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call `runnableProcessor.run();`, which is *not* deprecated (and as `Runnable` only has one method, `run`, it can't be deprecated without the whole class becoming deprecated too).

Answer (score 5):

Calling `run` is not deprecated and should be called for specific instances where sequential processing is required.

Alternatively you can have all your logic in a separate method, and call that method instead of calling `run`. `run` too will call this method inside it:

```
run(){
doOp();
}

public doOp(){
//all your code here
}
```

Caller can call `doOp` instead of `run` but that effectively makes no difference!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `run()` is not deprecated, it's just a common mistake that people make when they're starting a new `Thread`, because where `Runnable` types are involved, people usually want to start a new `Thread`.

As you can see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), there is no deprecated tag there!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest approach:

1. If you want to run the class in a separate thread, call `start` method
2. If you don't want to run the class in a separate thread then call `run` method. Calling run will make the execution sequential in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `run()` method of the `RunnableProcessor`. As said before, it's not deprecated at all.

Or you can call a new `Thread`, just like you do in the multithreaded situation, start it, and call [`thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) so that the main thread will wait for the newly started thread to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Tis can be done in two approaches,

1.call the run() of RunnableProcess directly.

2.Move the logic to separate separate method and call that method in the non multithreaded scenario. that method must also be invoked inside the run().

```
run(){
    do();
}

do(){
    //your code here
}



if(multithreaded)
    new Thread(runnableProcess).start();
else
    runnableProcess.do();
```